# Iframe alternative

Tags: servlets, iframe, extjs4.2

I need to display some html doc in specific location on my page (in some extJS panel, if details). I cannot use iframe, because my page is already displayed in an iframe and Internet Explorer does not support this.

The Html doc generate servlet, and I can get simple html text or doc in html format.

What iframe alternative can I use to display my doc in IE?

Answer (score 0):

A div given a scrollbar with css, i.e.

```
<div style="overflow:auto; height:400px; width:200px;">
```

You can use Ajax to populate it if necessary.